# Using color settings in XAML

Tags: json, xaml, uwp

We are working on setting collor setting stored in a JSON file for the user. But when I bind to the color in my XAML it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please review the help section if you're confused on how to post quality questions. Make sure that you're including code in your question and also a comprehensive overview of any errors, or problems you're seeing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind to a color directly to use. You have to use a converter to get a `SolidColorBrush`. You can do it with this converter:

```
public class ColorToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (!(value is Windows.UI.Color)) return null;
        return new SolidColorBrush((Windows.UI.Color)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {  
        return null;
    }
}
```

More on using Converters, [see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert that color value to a `SolidColorBrush` in order to bind it to your controls.

Best way would be to write a converter that converts from your JSON value to a SolidColorBrush.

If you show some of your code, and what exactly the problem is we might be able to give more specific advice.